# Download large file on Android device

Tags: android

I'm writing an Android-app, a map application. To use the app, user should download the offline map file. The size of this file is 3GB... Is it possible/good idea to download such a big file in the app or do i have to ask the user to download the file on his/her PC and manualy copy the file to the android device?

Comment: It's fine to download this on the mobile, just look at how games do this which often download large extra files. Just create a proper download screen and only download on wifi unless explicitly told otherwise

Comment: Thanks for your advise. Do you know a good download script for this large files?

Comment: Download script? What are you talking about?

Comment: Please, you may take into account that 3 GB may be too much for a SD card.

Comment: I would not want to download 3gb onto my phone even with wifi. but of course it can be done provided there is enough space on the device.

Answer (score 1):

If you do want use the Android to download the file by itself, you shall use the download manager to perform the task for you:

```
public void startDownload(String url, String fileName) {
    Uri resource = Uri.parse(url);   
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(resource);   
    request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(Request.NETWORK_WIFI);   
    request.setAllowedOverRoaming(false);   
    //set the file type 
    MimeTypeMap mimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();  
    String mimeString = mimeTypeMap.getMimeTypeFromExtension(MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url));  
    request.setMimeType(mimeString);  
    //show notification
    request.setShowRunningNotification(true);  
    request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);  
    //set target directory
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("YOURCACHEDIR", fileName);  
    request.setTitle("Offline MAP downloading");   
    DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);  ;
    long id = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
    Log.i(TAG, "Start download, id = " + id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would spare the user from the hassle of downloading it on his/her PC and then copying the file to the phone. A phone is very well capable of downloading such a big file, providing, of course, the phone has enough storage left.

I would however, advise that your app downloads this file via WIFI, with an optional option of downloading over the mobile network anyway.